# Unity Material Override Video is too dark

Tags: unity, blender, materials, video

I have made a TV in Blender, UV Wrapped a material and applied a  video on it in Unity.
But the picture is too dark, and I would like to make it brighter.

How could I solve this problem?

The left one
[image: It is the left one]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What material are you using on this object?

Comment: I am gonna add more details to the original post

Comment: Have you considered using an unlit material here, if you don't want the video shadowed when it's not facing the light?

Comment: DMGregory - Ohh I did not know this solution. Thank you :)  - I will leave the question here however because I would like to see different solutions
Is it possible to give it glove when I use Unlit Material?

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer below. Glow is a post-process effect, so you'll add that separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Material.
Shader -> Unlit -> Texture